# Similarity transform of a matrix preserves the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, proof-explanation

It is posited (in chapter $11$ of the book *Numerical Recipes in C*) that doing a similarity transform of a matrix $A$ preserves its eigenvalues. This is how a similarity transform is defined:

$$A \mapsto Z^{-1}AZ$$
for some transformation matrix $Z$ whose determinant is one. The proof given uses the characteristic equation.

$$|Z^{-1} A Z - \lambda I| = |Z^{-1}(A-\lambda I)Z| $$
I don't understand how this comes about. Once we accept this, the result follows quite easily:

$$= |Z||A-\lambda I||Z^{-1}| = |A-\lambda I|.$$

Comment: Which part exactly are you confused about? The equality $Z^{-1}AZ-\lambda I=Z^{-1}(A-\lambda I)Z$, or the fact that $|Z^{-1}(A-\lambda I)Z|=|Z||A-\lambda I||Z^{-1}|$?

Comment: I'm confused about the first part.

Comment: I have added ([tag:proof-explanation]) tag - see [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-explanation/info) - since your questions seems to be about this specific proof (rather than asking for *any* proof of the claim in the title). Of course, if this is incorrect, feel free to remove this tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that scalar matrices commute with all other matrices. Therefore
$$\lambda I=\lambda IZ^{-1}Z=Z^{-1}\lambda IZ$$
It then follows that
$$ Z^{-1}AZ-\lambda I=Z^{-1}AZ-Z^{-1}\lambda IZ=Z^{-1}(A-\lambda I)Z$$

Answer (score 7):

I'll write $\det(A)$ to mean the determinant $|A|$ of $A$. Then

\begin{align*}
\det(Z^{-1}AZ-\lambda I) 
&= \det(Z^{-1}AZ-\lambda Z^{-1}Z) \\ 
&= \det(Z^{-1}AZ- Z^{-1}\lambda I Z) \\  
&= \det(Z^{-1})\det(A- \lambda I )\det(Z) \\  
&= \det(Z)\det(Z^{-1})\det(A- \lambda I )  \\ 
&= \det(A- \lambda I ).  \\ 
\end{align*}